# How to test Documentum RESTful APIs

Tags: api, rest, documentum

I'm successfully running the Documentum Developer Edition on a Virtual Machine as suggested by Documentum's Official Site. I have access to the admin page, and now i'd like to test the RESTful apis to check if it's corrently working, to get an idea on how Documentum works.
Do you know how to do it? What URLs can i visit with the Virtual Machine's browser to test REST apis (possibly with the GET method)?
Please note that i currently can't access the official ecm documentation for office reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running *Documentum xCP 2.1 Developer Edition*. I doubt that REST services on *Documentum 7.0/7.1 Developer Edition* have different base URL address but check few usual ports at server with either `dctm-rest` or `documentum-rest` path.

If by chance you are running xCP 2.1 DE try with

```
http://demo-server:8080/dctm-rest/repositories/MyRepo
```

It'll list you repository details. 
As you can assume

```
http://demo-server:8080/dctm-rest
```

is the base URL for Documentum REST services. You can play from there. Best part is to create stateless process which you'll consume as REST services from your client. ;)

For help check out these links:

- https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-32266
- http://tagsalad.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/emc-documentum-platform-rest-services-tutorial/
- https://apicorner.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/documentum-releases-rest-resources/

When you gain access to official documentation you'll have 489 pages big Development Guide.

Comment: Nice, do you know how can i choose between XML and JSon?

Comment: i registered myself, but after clicking on a resource the destination page tells i'm not authorized to access that page. It seems i'm not able to view all resources.

Comment: try adding headers in your request, 'application/vnd.emc.documentum+json' should be for JSON format. Regarding linked resources - sorry, I couldn't have know, try googling around on that topic, there's a plenty of resources available publicly

Comment: where do i get dctm-rest folder?

Comment: The way you asked it sounds like a reasonable answer would be the 'just create new folder and name it like you want'. Its an OOTB application providing REST interface to Documentum repository for mostly use ECM actions. I suppose you could ask OpenText for it but thats another long story. :)